# Python program stops after for-loop with input inside it is finished

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, input

Im writing the code in text editor and execute it by double clicking the code. The code is fairly simple:

```
n_inp = int(input("N: "))
num = []
for i in range(n_inp):
    num.append(int(input("Number: " )))
print(num)
```

but for some reason the program just stopped after the loop is finished. It never prints the num, the program just closed. I tried using sleep command after the print(num) to see if it changes anything but it doesnt. Is there a problem with the code? Or should i just use some IDE to execute it? Thanks in advance.

edit: the code runs fine when executed from command prompt, i just wont run a code by double clicking again.

Comment: Does double clicking run it at all? Do you see the prompts you expect? Can you `print` other stuff unrelated to the loop? Since this may be an OS specific issue, what OS are you using? Are you using a version of Python that came with the OS, or have you installed it separately? Which version of Python are you running?

Comment: Yes it does run the program, the program just stopped after the loop is finished. OS is windows 10, python is 3,7,2.  I dont think theres a problem with my OS/Python, since I can execute any other python code fine. This problem only occur when I tried using input inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

but i tried the same code in python3 it's working correctly...

num prints the output like....

```
 N: 3
 Number: 12
 Number: 13
 Number: 14
 [12, 13, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to see the output because it will close the terminal immediately after printing the output. You can just add `sleep` after the `print(num)` statement. Try the following code.

```
import time
n_inp = int(input("N: "))
num = []
for i in range(n_inp):
    num.append(int(input("Number: " )))
print(num)
time.sleep(10)
```

or add one more `input()` after the `print` statement so that it will wait until you press any other button.

```
n_inp = int(input("N: "))
num = []
for i in range(n_inp):
    num.append(int(input("Number: " )))
print(num)
input()
```